# C#, Form.Timer interval value adjusting in a worker thread

Tags: c#

I want to modify interval value of timer which is instance of System.Microsoft.Timer from a worker thread
When i change this value in the thread running worker thread, Timer is stopped.

let see my source code

```
    private void Scan_Screen(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "a";
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        g_RECEIVER_timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        g_RECEIVER_timer.Enabled = true;
        g_RECEIVER_timer.Interval = TIMER_INTERVAL;
        g_RECEIVER_timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Scan_Screen);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        g_Control_Thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Control_Message_Receiver));
        g_Control_Thread.Start(200); 
    }
    //thread function
    public void Control_Message_Receiver(object v)
    { 
        g_RECEIVER_timer.Stop();
        g_RECEIVER_timer.Interval = 200;
        g_RECEIVER_timer.Enabled = true;
        g_RECEIVER_timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Scan_Screen);
    }
```

Why this happening is occurred? Also how can i make this run? (I want to adjust interval value of timer in the worker thread)

Comment: hard to tell without seeing how your timer is declared (could be a thread access issue), but one potential problem: are you intending to add multiple event handlers to the tick event? I suggest you debug your thread method! How do you know it has stopped?

Comment: Since you called `.Stop();` perhaps calling `.Start()` after setting the new interval

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke this `Control_Message_Receiver` on the UI thread since you have spawned another worker thread and you are accessing objects on the UI thread context.

And **don't** need to re-declare the Tick event on your worker thread method.

Look at this snippet below:

```
    private void Scan_Screen(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "a";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        g_RECEIVER_timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        g_RECEIVER_timer.Enabled = true;
        g_RECEIVER_timer.Interval = 1000;
        g_RECEIVER_timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Scan_Screen);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread g_Control_Thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Control_Message_Receiver));
        g_Control_Thread.Start(1);
    }

    //thread function
    public void Control_Message_Receiver(object v)
    {
        //timer1.Stop(); //why stop? -- remove this instead
        IntervalChange((int)v); //call this method and invoke it on the UI thread
        g_RECEIVER_timer.Enabled = true;
        //timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(Scan_Screen); // -- remove this
    }

    delegate void intervalChanger(int time);

    void ChangeInterval(int time)
    {
        g_RECEIVER_timer.Interval = time;
    }

    void IntervalChange(int time)
    {
        this.Invoke(new intervalChanger(ChangeInterval), new object[] {time}); //invoke on the UI thread
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to use [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). This one can be readjusted from any thread. Note, however, that the timer callback runs in a threadpool thread. So you have to use Invoke, if you need to access the GUI from this callback.